# Some CSV exports from SQL DEVELOPER aren't turning out right

Tags: sql, excel, csv, oracle-sqldeveloper, export-to-csv

I write a query, then try to export:

[image]

[image]

If I'm lucky, I get a list of just the values.  Other times, I get this:

[image]

Any idea what the issue is?

Comment: if you get insert statements it's because you've set the Format to INSERT vs CSV

Comment: embarrassing :/

Comment: no worries @jayykaa! we've all been there :)